# Why not showing liked icon when page refresh in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am making like and dislike functionality in ionic app when user like then want to show heart icon and when user dislike then want to show empty heart icon.When like the post then icon show but when refreshing page then its show icon of empty likes.Please help me how to resolve this problem in ionic....

**tab1.page.html**

```
      <div>
        <img src="{{getImage.image}}" (click)="tapPhotoLike(getImage.id)" (click)="toggleIcon(getImage.id)">
      </div>

      <p no-margin no-padding>
        <button clear ion-button icon-only class="like-btn">
          <!-- <ion-icon no-padding name="like_btn.icon_name" color="{{ like_btn.color }}" class="icon-space"></ion-icon> -->
          <ion-icon name="heart-empty" *ngIf="!iconToggle[getImage.id]" color="{{ like_btn.color }}"></ion-icon> 
          <ion-icon name="heart" *ngIf="iconToggle[getImage.id]" color="{{ like_btn.color }}"></ion-icon> 
        </button>
      </p>
```

tab1.page.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../user.service';
import { User } from '../user';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { ToastController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { LoadingController, NavController } from '@ionic/angular';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab1',
  templateUrl: 'tab1.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab1.page.scss']
})

export class Tab1Page implements OnInit {
  num
  getImages: User[] = [];
  getImages2: User[] = [];
  getImages3 = [];
  getcounts;
  countLikes
  counts
  unlikes
  likesID
  iconToggle = [];
  like_btn = {
    color: 'danger',
    icon_name: 'heart-empty'
  };

  public tap: number = 0;
  public status: false;
  constructor(private userService: UserService,
    public toastController: ToastController,
    private storage: Storage,
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public loadingController: LoadingController) {

  }

  doRefresh(event) {
    this.userPost();
    setTimeout(() => {
      event.target.complete();
    }, 2000);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userPost();
    //this.getCountOfLikes();
  }

  async userPost() {
    const loading = await this.loadingController.create({
      message: 'Please wait...',
      spinner: 'crescent',
      duration: 2000
    });
    await loading.present();
    this.userService.getUserPost().pipe(first()).subscribe(getImages => {
      this.getImages3 = getImages;
      loading.dismiss();
    });
  }

  likeButton() {
    const detail_id = this.userService.getCurrentIdpostId();
    this.storage.get('userId').then((val) => {
      if (val) {
        let user_id = val
        this.userService.userPostLikes(user_id, detail_id).pipe(first()).subscribe(
          async data => {
            this.iconToggle[this.num] = true;
            if (data['status'] === 'you have already liked this post') {
              const toast = await this.toastController.create({
                message: 'you have already liked this post before.',
                duration: 2000
              });
              toast.present();
            }
            this.userPost();
          }
        );
      }
    });
  }

  tapPhotoLike($detail_id, num) {

    this.userService.setCurrentIdpostId($detail_id);
    this.tap++;
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (this.tap == 1) {
        this.tap = 0;
        //this.unlikePost();
      } if (this.tap > 1) {
        this.tap = 0;

      }
    }, 250);
  }
  setIconToggles() {
    let x = 0;
    this.getImages3.forEach(() => {
      this.iconToggle[x] = false;
      x++;
    });
  }
  toggleIcon(num) {
    if (this.iconToggle[num]) {

      this.iconToggle[num] = false;
      this.unlikePost();
    } else {

      this.iconToggle[num] = true;
      this.likeButton();
    }
  }

  ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.userPost();

  }

  unlikePost() {
    let detail_id = this.userService.getCurrentIdpostId();
    this.storage.get('userId').then((val) => {
      if (val) {
        let user_id = val;
        this.userService.unLikes(user_id, detail_id).subscribe(async dislikes => {
          this.unlikes = dislikes;
          this.iconToggle[this.num] = false;
          this.userPost();
        })
      }
    });
  }

}
```

How manage icon , i am inserting status on like and dislike in database..In this code how to manage status please help me.

Comment: How to manage according to status...